# Why are most examples still using MySQL Extension if it's deprecated?

Tags: php, mysql

...rather than using PDO or mysqli?

I see a lot of new questions which get answered with examples using the old extension. I'm sure there must be a good reason but I can't find it.

Thanks

EDIT: to reformulate the question: Should I keep on using MySQL Extension as suggested by most examples on this site, rather than switching to PDO/MySQLi?

Comment: I like to call it `w3schools` syndrome.

Comment: Or, perhaps living in a world of millions of lines of legacy code - a major undertaking to rewrite, but still must be maintained.,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until PHP 5.3, `mysqli` did not support persistent connections. This means it had not been used in real, heavy production before then (which is not so long ago, given also the pain it is, in real, heavy production, to switch from PHP 5.2 to 5.3). Maybe now it is ok, but this fact makes me suspicious: it might have been written more with OOP than with performance in mind. And OOP is not an issue in a big project, since there will most likely be a layer above `mysql`/`mysqli`/`PDO` anyhow. BTW, prepared statements appear to be generally slower than not prepared statements (e.g., see [here](http://erlycoder.com/69/php-mysql-prepared-sql-statement-vs-sql-statement)), and there are other means of protection against SQL injection. To think that something must be better because it's newer and heavily advertised is just as bad as unconditionally sticking to the good old stuff.

That said, the answer to your question is probably: because many experienced coders still use the old extension. They are more used to it, and don't feel the urge to switch over (because the advantages of `mysqli`/`PDO` are marginal - until the old `mysql` extension gets phased out, of course!).

Comment: a) PHP5.3 is over 3 years old now and (in the meantime) even 5.4 is out. This _is_ a long time. b) `mysql` is not maintained anymore, thus one can definitely say "Yes, `mysqli`/`PDO_Mysql` _is_ better, because it's newer". c) I don't think you realize the benefits of a clean design, if you call it "marginal"...

Comment: @KingCrunch: I knew you would downvote me, it's your "educating" German nature (I'm German too, so I can say it). a) I know a LARGE website that has not switched to PHP 5.3 yet, because doing so would be a big headache. b) `mysql` IS maintained, as you can read [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php) at the bottom of the page. c) I do realize the benefits of a clean design when they are useful.

Comment: I don't think, you really expected my downvote, because I'm not interested in educating anybody. But others may read your post and may come to the conclusion (even if I cannot see, wether you are pro or con `mysql`), that _starting_ with `mysql` may be a good idea. There are even PHP4 libraries out there and it's good, that someone keeps an eye on it. But looking at this libraries shouldn't encourage anybody to write PHP4 libraries himself. (sidenote: The "maintenance only" mentioned on the linked page is more a "keep it alive somehow" ;) because many sites rely on it). My 2ct

Answer (score 3):

There is no good reason, just bad habit. Most existing tutorials are just old, thus beginners think, that the old `mysql`-extension is *the* way to connect to a mysql-database.

Answer (score 1):

Habit, plus loads of tutorials are out of date.